# Creating a builder with some constants and other variables

Tags: kotlin

```
kotlin 1.3.61
```

I have the following class and not sure if its the best design for creating a builder. Basically, the sales and product will have different constants for the icon and background. But the title and description can be changed. There could be other constants added i.e. technical. So the user of this class doesn't have to worry how this constants are created.

But the title and address need to be provided from outside of the class. In creating my builder I have used the `copy` to update the title and description. And not sure if this is the best way to do do this?

```
class Marketing {
    data class Model(
        val title: String = "",
        val description: String = "",
        val icon: Int,
        val background: Int)

    class Builder() {
        private var title: String = ""
        private var description: String = ""

        private val PRODUCT = Model(
            icon = 111111,
            background = 333333)

        private val SALES = Model(
            icon = 222222,
            background = 444444)

        fun title(title: String): Builder {
            this.title = title
            return this
        }

        fun description(description: String): Builder {
            this.description = description
            return this
        }

        fun buildProduct(): Model {
            return PRODUCT.copy(title = title, description = description)
        }

        fun buildSales(): Model {
            return SALES.copy(title = title, description = description)
        }
    }
}
```

And I am using it like this:

```
val product = Marketing.Builder()
    .description("this is the description of the product")
    .title("this is the title of the product")
    .buildProduct()

val sales = Marketing.Builder()
    .description("this is the description of the sales")
    .title("this is the title of the sales")
    .buildSales()
```

As you can see its easy to create different products by calling the appropriate builder i.e. `buildProduct()` and `buildSales()`

Many thanks for any suggestions to make this better

Comment: Do you really need to mimic the default Java Builder approach, i.e. using function instead of property access style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can consider using `sealed` classes like this:

```
sealed class Model(
    open val title: String,
    open val description: String,
    val icon: Int,
    val background: Int
) {
  data class Product(override val title: String, override val description: String) :
      Model(
          title,
          description,
          111111,
          333333)

  data class Sales(override val title: String, override val description: String) :
      Model(
          title,
          description,
          111111,
          333333)
}
```

This way:

- You have unified types (i.e. Same super class thus you can pass them around with the same type (`Model`))
- You can have different and/or common functionalities for all of them

Advantages:

You can pass the instances as `Model` and treat all of the instances the same and/or check them in a when clause for the proper type to act on (which does not require an else branch if used as an expression):

```
fun showModel(model: Model){
    title.text = model.title
}
```

or you can do:

```
fun doSomething(model: Model) = when (model) {
    is Product -> Unit
    is Sales -> Unit
}
```

You can read more about sealed classes [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html#sealed-classes).

Comment: I like this answer. But can  you explain more about what it means to have `unified types` Thanks

Comment: @ant2009 Yeah sure. I will edit my post and add some explanations in a bit.

Answer (score 4):

I honestly don't see why it isn't just two methods:

```
fun buildProduct(title: String, description: String): Model {
    return Model(icon = 111111, background = 333333, title = title, description = description)
}

fun buildSales(title: String, description: String): Model {
    return Model(icon = 222222, background = 444444, title = title, description = description)
}
```

Or maybe

```
class Builder(private val title: String, private val description: String) {
    fun buildProduct(): Model {
        return Model(icon = 111111, background = 333333, title = title, description = description)
    }

    fun buildSales(): Model {
        return Model(icon = 222222, background = 444444, title = title, description = description)
    }
}
```

If you want `title` and `description` to be always named, it doesn't look like a `Model` with empty title and description is actually useful (is it?) so instead of making them default arguments, I would add an extra class

```
data class Model(
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val icon: Int,
    val background: Int)

class Builder() {
    data class ModelTemplate(val icon: Int, val background: Int) {
        // optionally check that title and description aren't empty, or are valid in some other way
        fun build(title: String, description: String) = Model(icon, background, title, description)
    }

    private val product = ModelTemplate(icon = 111111, background = 333333)
    private val sales = ModelTemplate(icon = 222222, background = 444444)

    private var title: String = ""
    private var description: String = ""

    fun title(title: String): Builder {
        this.title = title
        return this
    }

    fun description(description: String): Builder {
        this.description = description
        return this
    }

    fun buildProduct(): Model {
        return product.build(title = title, description = description)
    }

    fun buildSales(): Model {
        return sales.build(title = title, description = description)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to say that it is not safe to use single builder to build multiple types. It would be better to separate it into specific classes, maybe with some shared base class. So my answer is:

**Model classes**

```
open class BaseModel(val icon: Int, val background: Int)
class ProductModel(val title: String, val description: String, icon: Int, background: Int) : BaseModel(icon, background)
class SalesModel(val title: String, val description: String, icon: Int, background: Int) : BaseModel(icon, background)
```

**Builders**

```
abstract class BaseBuilder<T : BaseModel> {
    abstract var icon: Int
    abstract var background: Int

    abstract fun build(): T
}

class ProductBuilder : BaseBuilder<ProductModel>() {
    override var icon = 222222
    override var background = 444444
    var title = ""
    var description = ""

    override fun build() = ProductModel(title, description, icon, background)
}

class SalesBuilder : BaseBuilder<SalesModel>() {
    override var icon = 111111
    override var background = 333333
    var title = ""
    var description = ""

    override fun build() = SalesModel(title, description, icon, background)
}
```

**And finally, Marketing class**

```
class Marketing {
    companion object {
        fun buildProduct(filler: ProductBuilder.() -> Unit) : ProductModel {
            return ProductBuilder().run {
                filler()
                build()
            }
        }
        fun buildSales(filler: SalesBuilder.() -> Unit) : SalesModel {
            return SalesBuilder().run {
                filler()
                build()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this way you can create models easily and safe:

```
val product = Marketing.buildProduct {
    title = "title"
    description = "descr"
}
```

***Mandatory field***

If you want to make some property unchancheable, you can replace it from `var` property into constructor with `val`. Example for `title` property:

**Builder**

```
class ProductBuilder(val title: String) : BaseBuilder<ProductModel>() {
    override var icon = 111111
    override var background = 333333

    var description = ""

    override fun build() = ProductModel(title, description, icon, background)
}
```

**Builder calling**

```
fun buildProduct(title: String, filler: ProductBuilder.() -> Unit) : ProductModel {
    return ProductBuilder(title).run {
        filler()
        build()
    }
}
```

**Using**

```
val product = Marketing.buildProduct("title") {
    //title = "title" - this line wouldn't be compiled anymore
    description = "descr"
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks great answer. But I do like the sealed class implementation